# Is there a Json schema validation implementation give all the missing required fields?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Normally, when validate a complicated json object, if an embedded field is required but the parent which is also required is missing, a validator only give the result saying the parent is required.

Wondering if there is a way (an implementation of json schema validator) to find all the mandatory fields (in the leaves of a json object) by applying a json schema validation?

Using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

With schema

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "name"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "firstName",
        "secondName"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "secondName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To validate an empty json object {}.

Can only get one error Message:
*Required properties are missing from object: name.
Schema path: #/required*

Can a validator give all the required fields including first and second names back in the error message?

Comment: I don't think that will work, since it cannot know (in the general case) what children of a non-existing object should be there. Imagine a case where the parent object is a list. Do you want to get an infinite number of error messages, one for each non-existing element in a non-existing list?

Comment: Interesting. The list can be a slight different scenario, we cannot say a list is $required$. The most closed keyword to $required$ for an array can be $minItems$, but they are still different. 

Let's reduce the scope of the question to along the $required$ chain, can we detect all the mandatory fields in the leaves using json schema with missing parents?

Comment: I still think that conceptually doesn't make sense, because if the parent is missing, all its children are missing, too. You could write a method that writes out all the required fields in all the levels, but that's just a static analisis of the schema then. If you inverse your question, things might get more clear: How would you identify _existing_ fields of a non-existing parent? You can't, because the parent isn't there.

Comment: En.. Exactly, if we want to know all the mandatory leaf fields, a static analysis will do. However, given a json object and a schema, we should be able to dynamically infer which leaf fields are missing. 
The inverse of the question loses the context of the required keyword which is of the knowledge of the parent. I think it is a different question.